# I am using BigqueryIO.write().to(new DynamicDestination).with Straming insert

Tags: apache, insert, google-bigquery

I am using

```
 BigQueryIO.<Map<String, String>>write().withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                        .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                        .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.neverRetry())
                        .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
```

In which streaming insert is making records duplicate internally without my control on it is shown in documentation.
After searching I found that I should explicitly specify insert-id that can avoid duplicates

But I am not able to figure out that where can I provide `insertId`

Note:- I can not use `BigQueryIO.Write.Method.FILE_LOAD` bcz I need to use get failed inserts.